# Template Argument Deduction guide for unique_ptr argument type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Is it possible to write a deduction guide so that an instance of `Simple` can be declared without template arguments? I've tried but cannot get the correct form to extract the `std::unique_ptr` element type.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template< class T >
class Simple
{
public:
    Simple( std::unique_ptr< T >& u ) :
    u_( u )
    {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr< T >& u_;
};

class MyThing
{};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr< MyThing > upSimple;
    Simple( upSimple ); // error C2955: 'Simple': use of class template requires template argument list
}
```

Comment: The most vexing parse strikes again!

Comment: Once you fix the vexing parse bug, it still doesn't compile - does MSVC not support CTAD yet?

Comment: Following on from @rakete's observation, this compiles (under gcc): `Simple s ( upSimple );`, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/V4bp2fsfk49cYMSd

Comment: @Barry The latest MSVC does. https://godbolt.org/z/Z1pXRo

Comment: @Rakete1111 I never know which MSVC to pick from that list, lol. Noted :-)

Comment: `Simple{upSimple}` ?

Comment: @Barry Don't forget the "latest" flag! :)

Comment: Ok, yes, your comments lead me to the fix! Replacing Simple( upSimple ) with Simple{ upSimple } _and_ setting the C++ Language Standard to /std:c++17 in the project settings allows this to compile as is! Thanks @Rakete1111 !

Comment: Can someone write up an answer to this instead of a sequence of comments?  :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a deduction guide so that an instance of Simple can be declared without template arguments? I've tried but cannot get the correct form to extract the std::unique_ptr element type.

The problem is another.

The implicitly generated deduction guides are perfectly able to extract the correct type template parameter for `Simple`.

As pointed by Rakete1111, this is a sort of "most vexing parse" problem.

Writing

```
Simple( upSimple );
```

your intention was to obtain the initialization of a unnamed temporary object of type `Simple` (`Simple<MyThing>`, thanks to new C++17 implicitly generated deduction guides) initialized with the object `upSimple`.

Unfortunately the compiler (visual-c++, but the same with g++ and clang++) interpret it as the declaration of a new variable (observe that parentheses declaring C++ variables are superfluous but perfectly legal; with `int (i);` you declare a variable `i` of type `int`) of name `upSimple` and type `Simple`.

This give an error because

(1) `upSimple` is defined in the preceding line so we have a redeclaration of `upSimple`

(2) implicitly generated deduction guides are unable, without a constructor argument, to deduce the template argument `T` for `Simple`.

To avoid this ambiguity, and obtain the initialization of a `Simple<MyThing>` object, you can save the value in a variable with

```
auto s = Simple(upSimple);
```

or also with

```
Simple s(upSimple);
```

so the compiler can't interpret the line as declaration of variable `upSimple` anymore.

If you really want an unnamed temporary object, you can use uniform initialization (you can use braces instead of parentheses)

```
//.....V..........V
Simple { upSimple };
```

that can't be interpreted as variable declaration.

And, yes: also the imposition of the use of new C++17 standard (through `/std:c++17` or `-std=c++17` or whichever is required from specific compiler) can be useful.